# breezejs createEntity is undefined

Tags: angularjs, breeze, angularjs-directive

Inside an AngularJS directive, I assign a new value to a scope variable:

```
$scope.myPerson = { TiersId: 105191, Name: "John Smith" };
```

Originaly the $scope.myPerson was created from a BreezeJS entity.

Assigning the new value triggers a $scope.apply() by AngularJS, which is then intercepted by BreezeJS. That's when it gets complicated.

**[EDIT]**

Ok, I've figured out that I need to use the EntityManager that I've registered with my dataContext:

```
$scope.myPerson =  myDataContext.createPerson({ TiersId: 105191, Name: "John Smith" });

  function createPerson(person) {
        return manager.createEntity("AccountOwner", person);
  }
```

Now, it fails in the following code:

```
  proto.createEntity = function (typeName, initialValues, entityState) {
    entityState = entityState || EntityState.Added;
    var entity = this.metadataStore
        ._getEntityType(typeName)
        .createEntity(initialValues);
    if (entityState !== EntityState.Detached) {
        this.attachEntity(entity, entityState);
    }
    return entity;
};
```

The entity type is known, but the createEntity(initialValues) function is undefined. How come ?

**[EDIT]**

To make things clearer, here's the relevant EF mapping as well as the model classes:

```
public class MandateMappings : EntityTypeConfiguration<Mandate>
{
    public MandateMappings()
    {
        Property(m => m.IBAN).HasMaxLength(34).IsFixedLength().IsUnicode(false);

        Property(m => m.AccountOwner.Name).HasMaxLength(70);  
        Property(m => m.AccountOwner.City).HasMaxLength(500); 

        Property(m => m.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(30);
        Property(m => m.UpdatedBy).HasMaxLength(30);
    }
}



public class Mandate : Audit
{  
    public string IBAN { get; set; }

    public AccountOwner AccountOwner { get; set; }

}

public class AccountOwner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Audit
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Edit: As of v 1.3.1 Breeze now DOES support inheritance.

Without more context I can't be sure, but I'm guessing that the issue is that Breeze does not YET have metadata about your entityType. Normally this is accomplished via your first query, but if you are creating entities before the first query then the alternative is to call the *EntityManager.fetchMetadata()* method instead BEFORE performing any createEntity calls.  The *fetchMetadata* method is asynchonous, i.e. returns a promise, so you will need to perform your createEntity call inside of the 'then' portion of the promise.  There are a couple of other recent 'Breeze' posts similar to this that have more details and examples.

Comment: I'll try to put together a jsfiddle. BUT: I do create this entity after I have already all the data loaded, including metadata. In fact, the type 'AccountOwner' is known to Breeze. Calling ._getEntityType(typeName) does return something, but it has no method called createEntity(). How is that possible ?

Comment: It can only happen, afaik, if the entityType cannot be found.  What is returned when you call manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("AccountOwner")?

Comment: I don't know, I'm away from my work computer right now. But what I know, is that in the beginning I was passing "Person" to manager.createEntity function. And I had an exception from Breeze because it could not find that type. And as a matter of fact, the correct type is "AccountOwner". Now that I'm passing this type, the code passes on _getEntityType and fails on createEntity because it does not exist. I'll have to check in details what was on the returned object, but it definitely had several methods and properties (but not createEntity )

Comment: could it be because of breeze version ? I see the ToDo sample still uses an old version. I'm using 1.3.0

Comment: Are you using inheritence in your object model. If so this could be the problem because Breeze doesn't yet support it.  ( we are working on it though) See: https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3083057-support-inheritence-in-the-object-model

Comment: ouch !!! it's not supported, really ? That's a huge problem for me then. All of my Model objects inherit from a Base object, which has common properties such as CreatedAt, CreatedBy, etc... Could that be the problem ?

Comment: Just had a look at your link. Ward's saying that object model inheritance IS supported. Only database inheritance is not supported. So who's right ?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  We hope to have inheritance involving common properties in a base class in soon... but it's not there now. Not sure what link you were reading from.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify what I meant when [I said on User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3083057-support-inheritence-in-the-object-model) that Breeze supports a form of inheritance but not "database inheritance".

I meant that, today, the classes on your server-side can be part of an inheritance chain **if and only if that chain is invisible to the client**.

Here are some conditions consistent with that caveat:

- Only the "terminal" class in the chain (the most derived class) maps to a database table.
- Properties on super classes are non-public (e.g., internal) or explicitly not mapped (e.g., adorned with `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]`.
- Methods may appear on any class at any level as these are never transmitted to the client.

Here is an example of a `TodoItem` class that inherits from a `baseClass`:

```
public class baseClass
{
    public void DoNothing() {}
    internal string Foo { get; set; }
}
public class TodoItem :baseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }                   

    [Required, StringLength(maximumLength: 30)]   
    public string Description { get; set; }       

    public System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }              
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }          
}
```

This works fine on the server. Set a breakpoint in the controller: you'll have no trouble executing `DoNothing()` and getting/setting the `Foo` property.

This works because **there is no client-side consequence of this structure**. The metadata are no different after deriving from `baseClass` than they were before. The `Foo` property and `DoNothing` methods are invisible to the client … exactly as **this service author** intended.

This kind of arrangement is pretty common in the real world where the many classes of a business model share functionality through a base class.

**This is NOT the end of the story and it is NOT what we think people are asking for when they ask for "inheritance".**

We think people want what I have been calling "database inheritance" by which I mean that two or more classes in the inheritance chain are mapped to different tables.

Breeze does not handle that today ... in part because Breeze cannot yet comprehend metadata that describe an inheritance hierarchy.

#### Workaround

What if you had a class hierarchy in which data properties were defined on different class levels? You can workaround the current obstacles by providing a metadata description that flattens the hierarchy from the perspective of the client.

For example, suppose you have a `Person` type with `FirstName` and `LastName`. And `Person` derives from `entityBase` which defines `createdBy`.

If you define the *Person* *EntityType* to have [`FirstName`, `LastName`, and `createdBy`] properties - essentially flattening the hierarchy - all will be well.

#### Flatten the hierarchy automagically

Of course that's a PITA. One approach to inheritance we could take is to do this flattening for you when you ask Breeze to generate the metadata on the server.

I'm curious: would this suffice? Or do you really NEED to know on the JavaScript client that the `createdBy` property belongs to a base class. If you really need to know, please tell me why.

Comment: it seems that I'm in the case where I've already flatten the data in the Entity definition - please see my EDIT in the original post. I've posted the relevant Entity Framework mapping as well as the model classes. Do you reckon this is going to be working with Breeze then ? In that case, the error I'm getting remains unexplained and things are not looking any brighter for me at the moment.

Comment: and also to answer your questions, I certainly don't need to know about inheritance on the JavaScript side, that's the last of my concern.

Comment: @Sam - I don't see where you flattened the metadata ... the **Breeze metadata**, not EF's metadata. Breeze can't do that for you yet. So you have to do it manually by defining your own **Breeze metadata** for the model. That's not hard to do but it can be tedious. Did you try it?

Comment: ok, then I didn't get it. How am I supposed to do that? Is it in the Metadata() function ? Could you provide a code sample based on what I've posted so far ?

Comment: Actually I believe that the backend design is not that great. I think it'd be better to have a AccountOwner table and just the AccountOwner unique id in the Mandate table. I don't know why it wasn't designed like that in the first place. This morning I've tried creating Entities of other type (including ones that have inheritance) and it seems to work (at least I no longer get the error about the createEntity method). So I believe my problem is just about that AccountOwner class being mapped to the Mandate Entity instead of a dedicated AccountOwner Entity. What do you think ?