# Breeze type inheritance on complex objects properties of a base type

Tags: breeze

Suppose I have the following classes on the server:

- class **A** which has a property **a**
- class **B** that derives from **A** and adds property **b**

I have another class, class **C** which has a property **c** of type **A**.

I provide the meta-information in my client by creating 3 complex objects (there is an entity **E** that has a property of type **CType**), one for each class type (**AType**, **BType**, **CType**) as follows (sorry this is TypeScript):

```js
export class EType {
    public static registerType(metadataHelper: breeze.config.MetadataHelper, store: breeze.MetadataStore): void {
        metadataHelper.addTypeToStore(store, {
            shortName: "E",
            namespace: "ns",
            defaultResourceName: "Es",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.None,
            dataProperties: {
                itemId: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String, isPartOfKey: true },
                e: { complexTypeName: "C" }
            }
        });
    }
}

export class AType {
    public static registerType(metadataHelper: breeze.config.MetadataHelper, store: breeze.MetadataStore): void {
        metadataHelper.addTypeToStore(store, {
            isComplexType: true,
            shortName: "A",
            namespace: "ns",
            dataProperties: {
                a: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String }
            }
        });
    }
}

export class BType {
    public static registerType(metadataHelper: breeze.config.MetadataHelper, store: breeze.MetadataStore): void {
        metadataHelper.addTypeToStore(store, {
            isComplexType: true,
            shortName: "B",
            namespace: "ns",
            dataProperties: {
                a: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String },
                b: { dataType: breeze.DataType.String }
            }
        });
    }
}

export class CType {
    public static registerType(metadataHelper: breeze.config.MetadataHelper, store: breeze.MetadataStore): void {
        metadataHelper.addTypeToStore(store, {
            isComplexType: true,
            shortName: "C",
            namespace: "ns",
            dataProperties: {
                c: { complexTypeName: "A" }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Once all types are registered to the store using the metadataHelper, I do the following:

```js
var bObject = (<breeze.ComplexType>metadataStore.getEntityType("B")).createInstance({ a: "aValue", b: "bValue" });
var cObject = (<breeze.ComplexType>metadataStore.getEntityType("C")).createInstance({ c: b });
var eObject = (<breeze.EntityType>metadataStore.getEntityType("E")).createEntity({ itemId: "001", e: c });
```

When I look at property **c** of object **cObject** in the debugger (in _backingStore), it shows me that it is an object of type **AType** (I was hoping to get a **BType**). And the **b** property of that object is not there anymore (since an **AType** has no **b** property).

Now I understand this is sort of correct, but I would like **c** to be able to hold objects of type **AType** and any subtype. But **BType** does not know it is a subtype of **AType**...

One answer to the question "[breezejs createEntity is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103214/breezejs-createentity-is-undefined/16125887#16125887)" seems to imply that this is something that is not supported.

What is the best practice for such metadata? Do I need to specify a type that encompasses both **AType** and **BType**, and make **CType**'s **c** reference that complex type instead? Or is there a better way to handle such inheritance in the metadata?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using complex types for this instead of entity types. ComplexTypes are really only for cases where there is no conceptual unique identity.

Comment: The reason is that this is how it is modeled on the server: I will request a given entity, which will then have a property of type "C" and a whole complex object structure). A change to any property of this complex object structure means that the entity was modified, and therefore needs to be provided back to the server to be persisted.

Comment: Then I think that you should be able to model this exactly as it appears on the server. Not sure I understand the issue.

Comment: Can you show your client metadata definition code? And in your example above are all of the classes A, B and C complex types or are some entity types.

Comment: I improved the question with a proper test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze currently supports EntityType inheritance but NOT ComplexType inheritance.